# Button under the current page getting clicked/tapped in sencha touch

Tags: windows, button, extjs, tap

I'm using sencha touch 2.3.1
I have a button on a page and clicking it will open a new page (above the current page). 
But when I click/tap on the new page in the region where the button is ( in the original page ) , the button is still getting clicked. 
And a new view of the same page is being opened. 
I'm facing this problem only in windows phone, it works fine in android, IOS and all browsers (including IE) through IIS. I'm using the tap event for this button. 
Please help me resolve this. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your issue is similar to this bug I've reported a while back:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?237550-2.1-Tap-event-is-passed-to-the-textfield-in-new-view

The workaround which has been working for me is adding `e.stopEvent();` to the tap handler of the component the user is tapping on.

Comment: It's not working for me, my function looks something like this..
tap: function(e, dom) {
e.stopEvent(); 
var el = Ext.get(e.target),
     .
     .
     .

Comment: I guess I'm doing something wrong because it doesn't look like it'll work. Can you please tell me how to do it properly, I'm new to sencha, so it's difficult for me

Comment: Do you think you can add more code to your original question? The snippet above looks ok, not sure what is wrong in your code.

Comment: I'm sure that e.stopEvent() is not working.
Right now, I'm using the following code inside the tap event:
if(Ext.getCmp('center-report')){
return false;
}
Where 'center-report' is the id of the new view that is opened after clicking the button. This works for me.

Comment: Would need to see some code to comment on that, you might have put e.stopEvent() in the handler you don't expect to be called, instead of the handler you expect to be called. (e.stopEvent() stops to bubble the event up, it's not stopping the actual handler you're adding it to) Glad you found a workaround though.